# How do i move these UV artifacts

Tags: uv

I UV unwrapped the object properly. These stretch artifacts pop out of nowhere and are ruining my model with weird jaggered lines
[image: artifacts in UV causing weird jaggered lines in object]

Answer (score 1):

The don't "pop out of nowhere" - the problem is your mesh topology.  See these vertices here, indicated in yellow:

[image]

Those vertices make the large face into a nasty n-gon, and so Blender has to add extra geometry to render it.

See for example this: [Subdivision problem during modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142277/subdivision-problem-during-modeling/142281#142281)

and

[Render shows geometry that isn't there. Normals?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80164/render-shows-geometry-that-isnt-there-normals/95353#95353)

To fix it, you need to connect those edge vertices to something, whether it's making more edges along the face or something similar.